# how MVC4 knows type of variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In the below code how MVC4 knows the type of variable "foo" is IEnumerable

```
@model IEnumerable<Xrm.Contact>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@foreach (var c in Model) { 
    <div>
<span> @Html.DisplayFor(foo => c.FirstName) </span>
<span> @Html.DisplayFor(foo => c.LastName) </span>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current view has a property, `Html` which is of type `HtmlHelper<TModel>`, where `TModel` is whatever type you've declared in the `@model` directive at the top of the file. So when you call the [`DisplayFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407390%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) extension method with `Html`, the compiler can infer the type of the expression you will provide in the second parameter.

Because the current model is `IEnumerable<Xrm.Contact>` that's what it assumes the parameter will be.